# Swiftmailer - Use of undefined constant INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46

Tags: php, centos6, php-7.1, intl

I have problems sending emails with laravel 5.5 because swiftmailer uses the constant `INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46`, but it is undefined. Take this example that reproduces the error:

```
if (extension_loaded('intl')) {
    echo INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46;
}
else{
    echo 'intl not loaded';
}
```

Once executed the following error is raised:

> Use of undefined constant INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46

Troubleshooting:

- PHP 7.1 phpinfo() confirms that intl extension is loaded
- Intl version 1.1.0, ICU version 4.2.1
- I used the funciont in order to test intl extension functions, and it works correctly:

  ```
  # ea-php71 -r '$a = numfmt_create( 'fr_FR_PARIS',  NumberFormatter::DECIMAL); print numfmt_get_locale( $a, Locale::VALID_LOCALE ) . "\n";'
  fr_FR
  ```
- Constants `INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_2003` is actually defined!

Why is INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46 undefined? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The constant `INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46` is accessible at that row?

Comment: Negative, the constanst is not defined is that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ext/intl/idn/idn.c:85-87

```
#ifdef HAVE_46_API
REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT("INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46", INTL_IDN_VARIANT_UTS46, CONST_CS | CONST_PERSISTENT);
#endif
```

Constant `INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46` needs C constant `HAVE_46_API`, which requires UTS#46 API:

```
#ifdef UIDNA_INFO_INITIALIZER
#define HAVE_46_API 1 /* has UTS#46 API (introduced in ICU 4.6) */
#endif
```

So, you need to upgrade your ICU.